# Why is nothing logging to the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```js
// This initializes the app.
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");

// Imports
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const { onDocumentCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp();

const firestore = getFirestore();

exports.app = onDocumentCreated(
    {
        region: "europe-west1",
        document: "/requests/{documentId}"
    },
    (event) => {
        console.log("Running.");
    }
);
```

This code above doesn't throw any errors, but the problem is that nothing logs to the console.

When I run this code in firebase emulators (using `firebase emulators:start`) after creating a document in the `requests` collection, no errors are thrown but nothing is logged. Anyone know why the code isn't logging anything?

Comment: Where do you write the first time into a document?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Which log do you expect and why?

Comment: I expect "running" to be logged.

Comment: When? You've registered an event handler for `onDocumentCreated`. When is this event fired? The given code wouldn't log `"Running"` because the event isn't triggered.

Comment: Might be related to [`firebase-tools`#6290](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6290). For now, try reverting back to v12.4.8.

Comment: @jabaa The event fires after a document gets created in the collection `requests` collection, but nothing happens when I do it.

Comment: Where do you create a document? I don't see it in your code snippet. According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events it's triggered when you write first time into the document.

Comment: I had created it manually on the firebase firestore console.

Answer (score 1):

I was modifying the actual firestore to test the emulator, instead of the emulator firestore, so the event wasn't triggering.